# Getting specified fields from ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the below query builder from my java class

```
SearchSourceBuilder()
                .query(BoolQueryBuilder()
                        .filter(QueryBuilders
                                .termQuery("cities.id", cityId)))
```

It's returning me all the properties of the cityId it matches. But I just need the name of the city.

How can I accomplish it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start! You simply need to call the `fetchSource()` method

```
SearchSourceBuilder()
    .fetchSource(new String[] {"name"}, null)                 <-- add this line
    .query(BoolQueryBuilder()
                 .filter(QueryBuilders
                            .termQuery("cities.id", cityId)))
```